# Finding the biggest sum of integers in an array but not bigger than x

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Let's say we've got an array of integers:

```
int array = {5, 7, 4, 4, 2}
int x=10
```

The output would be:

```
10 //(4,4,2)
```

What's the fastest way to achieve this output?

Comment: Have you made an attempt at any algorithm at all?

Comment: Sounds like homework. Pls tag it as such.

Comment: Well, I've got it working for integers that looks like 2^k, I dont know how to solve this one

Comment: If the array was `{5,3,4,1}` - would `(5,4,1)` be a good solution? If so - you have a [subset sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) over here.

Comment: sounds like a Subset_sum problem. See http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~ac/Teach/CS105-Winter05/Notes/nanda-scribe-3.pdf for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are dealing with a **[Subset Sum Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem)** (assuming you don't want contiguous sub-array).

The problem is [NP-Complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete), and there is no known polynomial solution to it (and the general assumption is that one does not exist, but [it is not proven yet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP_problem))

However, there is a [pseudo polynomial solution, using Dynamic Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem#Pseudo-polynomial_time_dynamic_programming_solution).

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are asking is similar to the

```
0-1 Knapsack problem
```

where the profit is same as weight.

You can google it and understand the algorithm easily.This is perhaps the fastest way.

Comment: @Karoly Horvath :Thanx for the comment.I have edited the answer.